Offsetting edges randomly on the Y axis with geometry nodes
I have a kind of square wave geometry (origin), and I want to randomly offset the top edges (desired). What am I doing wrong with my setup (result)? Why some edges are horizontal while others are slanted?


"Set Position" is inevitably on "point domain".
When you "Evaluate on Edge Domain" for something that asks values on a point domain, the edge values are interpolated (each vertice gets a value from two edges)
In order to exclude the vertical edges, you need your selection to be "greater than half height" instead of "greater than 0".
Then you store a random value "per edge" excluding the vertical edges from the selection, and use this stored value in the offset:


(PS: this answer is probably still interpolating, but interpolating between known values which are "top value" and "zero value" instead of a random value for each edge individually, for a non interpolated answer, you'd need to explore "edges of vertex" node, which can be a little complicated to understand)

A non interpolating answer
Here, we use "edges of vertex" to select the edge with the highest Y and we evaluate at the selected edge instead of interpolating:

Edges of vertex gets all edges connected to the target point
Weights are used to sort (order) the edges by some criteria (ascending sort)
Sort index 0 gets the first of the sorted edges.



It worked flawlessly -- thank you very much.
